# SharePoint InfoPath Task Form to retain it's state

Tags: infopath, 2007

I don't suppose there's a way to get an InfoPath task form to save it's state once it's submitted.

In a workflow I don't delete the tasks, I just set them to complete. I don't pre populate much of the task forms as it's down to the user to complete the form. Some of the task forms are quite important and I'd like them to retain their entered fields after the workflow has moved on, or even completed itself.

Answer (score 1):

Sadly I don't think there is a way to get them to save the state as such. They just send the data back the workflow and then close. One idea might be to add another data connection to the form to save it in to a Document Library - you could then store them in there for reference later.

It's a bit of a bodge but it would do the job.